# Why am I unable to push to GitHub on my new laptop?

Tags: git, git-push

I get a new Macbook. When I push my code into Github, it always fails:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/canvas-puzzle.git/': Empty reply from server
```

However, on the same network, I can push quickly from my old laptop running on Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you change `https` to `http`?

Comment: Maybe the curl version is too old (as in https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/13538)? What version of git do you have on the Macbook vs. on the Ubuntu?

Comment: @AndyJ0076 I have already tried.The process is so slow!And the situation is the same~

Comment: What's your `git --version`?  github help pages recommend >=`1.7.10`.

Comment: @AndyJ0076 git version is 2.0.1

Comment: Take a look at https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors/.  It's for https cloning problems, but it still might help.

Comment: I have the same problem